# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'FFI'

Tags: pi-zero, python-3

I am trying to set up Picovoice's Rhino to my Raspberry Pi Zero W. I have followed all the instructions on the website: [link](https://picovoice.ai/docs/quick-start/rhino-raspberrypi-quick-start/)
My RPi uses Python 3.4.2. I have updated the packages using:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Now when I try to run the demo file:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo rhino_demo_mic --context_path resources/contexts/raspberry-pi/smart_lighting_raspberry-pi.rhn
```

I am getting the following errors:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/rhino_demo_mic", line 7, in <module>
    from pvrhinodemo.rhino_demo_mic import main
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/pvrhinodemo/rhino_demo_mic.py", line 20, in <module>
    import soundfile
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/soundfile.py", line 17, in <module>
    from _soundfile import ffi as _ffi
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/_soundfile.py", line 4, in <module>
    ffi = _cffi_backend.FFI('_soundfile',
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'FFI'
```

I also downloaded the "libffi-dev" package, but can't seem to be able to solve the issue.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Python 3.4.2 was released **seven** years ago, and Python 3.4 reached end-of-life over two years ago. Time for an upgrade.

Comment: Having python 3.4.2 would also suggest you're on Raspbian Jessie. Definitely time for an upgrade.